# How to parse colon delimiter data in python when list style is different?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Cell 1, Cell 2, and Cell 3 are 3 rows within excel which contains the data I would like to parse - see below(initial data). I am trying to parse the information in each cell by respecting their value possible using python libraries or excel formulas. I am trying to create column for each line like the outcome data below(parsed data).

```
Cell 1
--------------------------------------------------
Employee:

Info: John Doe, John.Doe@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM

Manager:

Info: John Doe2, John.Doe2@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM
--------------------------------------------------

Cell2
--------------------------------------------------
Employee:

Info: John Doe3, John.Doe3@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM

Manager:

Info: John Doe4, John.Doe4@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM

Manager:

Info: John Doe5, John.Doe5@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM
--------------------------------------------------

Cell 3
--------------------------------------------------
Employee:

Info: John Doe5, John.Doe5@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM

Employee:

Info: John Doe5, John.Doe5@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM

Manager:

Info: John Doe, John.Doe@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM
--------------------------------------------------
```

[Initial Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsMBi.png)

[Parsed Data(outcome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyvWU.png)

Comment: There are a LOT of parts to this question to get from the initial state to the end state. What have you tried so far? What specific step are you stuck on? Happy to help, but we do need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Given a cell of data:

```
d = """Employee:

Info: John Doe3, John.Doe3@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM

Manager:

Info: John Doe4, John.Doe4@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM

Manager:

Info: John Doe5, John.Doe5@abc.com
Response: Yes
Request Date: Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM
Response Date: Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM"""
```

We can start to make it into a dataframe doing something like:

```
data = data = [x for x in d.splitlines() if x]
cols = ['designation', 'info', 'response', 'request_date', 'response_date']
times = len(data)//len(cols)

df = pd.DataFrame([[col,x] for col, x in zip(cols*times, data)])
df[2] = df.index//len(cols)

df = df.pivot(columns=0, index=2).droplevel(-2, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.apply(lambda c: [y if y else x for x, y in c.str.split(':', 1)])
```

Output:

```
0 designation                           info                         request_date response                       response_date
0    Employee   John Doe3, John.Doe3@abc.com   Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM      Yes   Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM
1     Manager   John Doe4, John.Doe4@abc.com   Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM      Yes   Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM
2     Manager   John Doe5, John.Doe5@abc.com   Wednesday, June 1, 2022 7:00:00 PM      Yes   Thursday, June 2, 2022 8:00:00 AM
```